# Good question was never answered

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I found this really good question about Remastersys that was never answered. [Looking for a free, usable alternative for remastersys](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11857/15370) Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Some questions here simply don't have good software that matches the criteria. If you know of something, feel free to add an answer. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Usually, the preferred way to draw attention to questions you feel need a better answer is by setting a bounty.

Comment: You spelled "remastersys" wrong.  You ended it with the string "rys" instead of "rsys".  This might make it harder for people using the search box to find this meta question.  Luckily, you can always [edit] your question and fix it.  Unfortunately, I can't, unless you tag your meta post with the "wiki" tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's one of mine. I've not found an answer that's worked for me the way I expected it to.

It's the nature of the beast, really. One of the reasons software recommendations are not really accepted on other sites is cause software goes obsolete. I'm still stuck looking for a replacement for a bit of software I'd consider indispensable since the original author stopped maintaining it, and as a non coder, I can't really fork it.

That's just how it is.

Comment: Are you really a non-coder?

Comment: For the most part yes. It is simply not one of my talents

Comment: Journeyman Geek, can I modified your question and repost it?

Comment: That might be a dupe. A better idea would be to bounty or find an answer.

Comment: @jo900: Or you can [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/11857/edit) Journeyman Geek's question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, Would you call yourself a DevOps?

Comment: nope. I'm no dev. I tend to think of myself as an hardware enthusiast, and more interested in the ops side of things.

Answer (score 2):

Like on other less popular sites of StackExchange, it will always be full of great question without attention. I think that is the problem, the main one.

> person who developed it had some clashes of personality with persons
>   unknown, and unfortunately stopped developing

Sounds just like he faced a very bad opinion on his program and it crashed his world.. Or he's just get married.

Comment: Yup. And most forks seem to be inactive. There's a whole unrelated rant about that.

Comment: A rant about all forks being inactive?  My, my.  People complaining about *somebody* else not doing free work.   Those that complain are presumably able to contribute their own efforts; if not, they shouldn't complain.